# How to add background image to div tag

Tags: html, css

```css
.slide{
 background-color: #000000;
 
    background-image: url('image/sample.jpg');

    width: 100%;
    height: 150px;
    max-width: 1920px; 
} 
.slide iframe{
     float:center; 
}
}
```

```html
        <div class="slide">
          <iframe  src=""> 
        </div>  <!-- end of slide div -->
```

'm trying to add background image to div tag.But I can't add it.I don't know what is wrong with my code.

I want to set the iframe in center where the background image displayed.
Now I cant display background image and frame is displaued in left instead of center.

Comment: You probably got a message telling you not to link to JSFiddle without also including your code in the question. That means you should include your code **in the question** and not tell stackoverflow that the link itself is code.

Comment: Your HTML is [invalid](http://validator.w3.org/) and your CSS is [invalid](http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/).

Comment: There is no such property as `float:center`

Answer (score 0):

You can add background image for a DIV like this:

```
div
{
background-image:url("image.jpg");
}
```

and about the iframe, if i understood correctly... did you try with `float:left;`

EDIT::

and there's no `float:center;`, there's only `float:left` and `float:right;`

are you trying to add background image to `iframe`, if so, you can do it like:

```
.slide iframe{background-image:url("image.jpg");}
```

or else if you want to add to the div, you can do..

```
.slide{background-image:url("image.jpg");}

.slide iframe{background-color:transparent;}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use property background-image.
Below is the example

```html
<style type="text/css">
.divbackg {
    background-image: url(http://www.boltoday.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/10/only-3d-natural-1024x768.jpg);
}
</style>




<html>
<div class="divbackg">
    div with background
</div>

</html>
```

Comment: I copied this code and paste it.still I have problem with this

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the Image has the wrong path. If your CSS file is in a folder, you must address it with two dots to reach the parent Directory.

Also the CSS `float:center` is invalid. Just make it an block element and Center it with `margin:auto;`

Answer (score 0):

make sure you set a right path to your image. If your image folder is located in a directory for the parent of css directory, try this

```
background-image: url('../image/sample.jpg');
```

Answer (score 0):

CSS Syntax: The `.slide` class is not closed properly in your CSS. The closing bracket `}` is not needed.

Float Property: The float property is used incorrectly. Instead of `float: center`, you should use `margin: 0 auto;` to center the element horizontally.

In order to achieve your task please modify the style implemented to your `.slide iframe` as follows.

```
.slide iframe {
    margin: 0 auto; /* Center the iframe horizontally */
}
```